# Drupal Shurly before redirect

Tags: hooks

I want  create to something like [adf.ly](http://adf.ly/) script with Drupal. I am using [shurly](http://drupal.org/project/shurly) (developed by Jeff Robins) for URL shortening, and it works fine, but I want to display an advertising page for 10 seconds before redirecting to the final URL, which is not a feature provided by this module.

It has a hook called `hook_shurly_redirect_before()` which may help me, but I don't have enough knowledge to use it.

Can anyone explain how I should use this hook?

Comment: Shurly module does its job during the bootstrapping so most of the standard Drupal functionality is unavailable here. You will need to include necessary files manually, theme the page through a template file, and then add a mata refresh or something. I'm not quite sure how to do it well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a quick glance at the shurly code, I'd think this should work:

```
function yourmodule_shurly_redirect_before(&$redirect) {
  $redirect->destination = 'path/to/advert?somevar='. $redirect->destination; 
}
```

And then you need to set up your advertisement page as path/to/advert and have it redirect to `$_GET['somevar']` after the timeout.